# Top Left Corner Icon Android

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I'm wondering if it is possible to make my own personal icon for when my app is running? I don't really want to worry about adding it to the notification scroll down menu. I just want the picture in the top left corner. Any help on how to go about doing this would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible to change the icon in the top left corner. You have to change the ic_launcher png file (in res/drawable). Don't forget to change it in the hdpi, mdpi and ldpi folder.

- for mdpi it should be 100X100
- for hdpi it should be 150:150
- for ldpi it should be 75:75

[Android screen sizes in Pixels for ldpi, mdpi, hpdi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168329/android-screen-sizes-in-pixels-for-ldpi-mdpi-hpdi)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. If you are going to have a `Notification`, you must have it in the notification drawer as well.

Comment: That is fine. My next question is, is there a way to close it. For instance i have an on and off button for a reason. if the button is off i do not want a notification on the top left but if the button is on this i do want the notification to be up there so i need a statement like  if(on) make notification if(off) remove notification

Comment: @au789: Please do not simply have a `Notification` there for no good reason. It should only be there if there is an event that has occurred in the background (e.g., `AlarmManager` and `IntentService` retrieved new email for the user), or if the user has started some background operation (e.g., `startForeground()` for a music player that the user started). All that being said, use `cancel()` on `NotificationManager` to remove a `Notification` that you raised.