# Android values-sw600dp is not working in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I currently have the default layouts all in the *layout* folder with default values in the *values* folder with the *dimens.xml* file inside.

I am using my tf101 tablet which is 1280*800. It works with the *values-sw800dp* folder.

But when I launch the same size screen on the emulator it just takes the default values instead of the ones from *values-sw800dp*

I have tried several different sizes of emulators all with their own values folder and none of them seem to work. I have tried restarting everything and deleting the emulators and re-creating them but I still can't seem to get it to take to the correct values folder using the emulator.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Please read [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/). Instead of telling us that it doesn't work and that you supposedly made it everything right, please tell us exactly which parameters you used so we can check for ourselves. I mean, don't take it the wrong way, but for what you told, you basically said nothing.

Answer (score 0):

800 pixels is not the same as 800 dp.

[Android screen sizes in Pixels for ldpi, mdpi, hpdi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168329/android-screen-sizes-in-pixels-for-ldpi-mdpi-hpdi)

Assuming you mean sw600dp and if your device is hdpi then 800 divided by 1.5 is too small for sw600dp.