# Media queries for android default "internet" browser?

Tags: android, media-queries

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 Android Version 2.3 and am trying to change some media queries for it. I am using this:
    @media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}

Which seems to be working for Chrome on Android, but not the native Android Browser. I've looked at what would target this browser and it says 360px W, 567px H, -webkit-pixel-ratio:2, but it is not working. Does anyone know how to get this browser to behave?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the pixel ratio to 1.5. I haven't actually tested this, however, it looks like the density may actually be 1.5 for hdpi devices (hdpi is 240dpi so it has a 1.5 pixel density over mdli, the baseline, which is 160dpi).

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {}
```

If this turns out to be correct, perhaps the core browser is just being stricter than Chrome and requiring you to enter the exact value.

The following article has a bit more detail: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html

I'm assuming the S3 uses hdpi graphics but if this is incorrect, the following Stack Overflow has a more complete list of pixel densities (Google's article is a little old so only goes up to hdpi): [Android screen sizes in Pixels for ldpi, mdpi, hpdi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168329/android-screen-sizes-in-pixels-for-ldpi-mdpi-hpdi)