# ImageView quality

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview

I've just finished my app, so I tested  it on a tablet, the quality is good, but when I try it on my smartphone (HTC One) I get a bad quality, so i wanna know why.

layour-normal:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:id="@+id/topLogo"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_bleu_petit"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

image-size: 250*107

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: read his http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168329/android-screen-sizes-in-pixels-for-ldpi-mdpi-hpdi

Comment: You need to provide different images for different screen densities.

Comment: Where the images comes from.. Is it dynamic or you are talking about logo_bleu_petit this image only

Comment: @quicklearner ive put the picture in all dimension folder, still not work

Comment: @BidhanA i tried to put the pic in the drawable dimensions folders still dont work

Comment: @Amsheer image frome drawable normal and i got less quality on all images of drawable normal

Comment: @quicklearner Look my edit

Comment: @BidhanA Look my edit

Comment: @Amsheer Look my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put different images in different folders of drawable.
For example,put the 250*107 image in /res/drawable-mdpi, and put a 500*214 version of the same image in /res/drawable-hdpi.
The app will display different images on devices with different screen size.
If you only have one low-quality image in /res/drawable,when you use a device with a 1080p screen,the image might be blown up to 2x or 4x.Then it looks in bad quality.

And one more thing,try not to use a fixed width or height on an ImageView.Use scaleType so the ImageView can perform better with images of different size.

Comment: Okay i'm gonna try it, but i dont understand, if normal layout = 50*50 / xlarge layout = 200*200, and drawable-mdpi = 25*25, drawable-hdpi= 75*75. I d'ont understand if xlarge choose in xhdpi and the image is little than him

Comment: Which drawable file is chosen is determined by the screen density.In general you don't need to set up different layout files

Comment: So i have to delete my drawable-small, drawable-normal, drawable-large, drawable-xlarge files ?

Comment: Just use one layout file,and put different size images in /res/drawable-ldpi,/res/drawable-mdpi,/res/drawable-hdpi. Don't forget to add scaleType to the imageView.

Comment: What scaleType i have to choose ? And the images dont gonna be high for smartphone  ?

Comment: You can try CENTER_INSIDE if you want to put the image in the center of the imageView. FIT_XY will scale the image to the size of the imageView.

Comment: Can you look of my edit if i have the good folders now ? Im gonna try what u said :)

Comment: How to do for tablet in portrait ?

Answer (score 0):

There are diffrent drawable folder in res folder of your project. You have to provide same image file with same name but diffrent sizes in diffrent drawable folders so that when you run your app in any devices it will automatically pic the image according to its resolution.

Comment: I dont understand so, layout normal/large/xlarge gonna choose what drawable dimensions folders ? And i put a high image resolution in all drawable dimension folders its dont work