# Ionic 3 - Image size for different resolutions: LDPI, MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI, XXHDPI, XXXHDPI

Tags: android-layout, ionic3, image-resizing, screen-resolution

I am developing an app with Ionic 3 and I would like to know how to handler images for different resolutions. I mean, I have the same image in different sizes (for LDPI, MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI, XXHDPI, XXXHDPI), but I don't know how to load the right image when I use:

```
<img src="img/thumbnail-totoro.png">
```

- Do I have to use a media query in css or to calculate the ratio in typescript?
- And finally, do I have to save these images into resources/android/images or assets/imgs? I think is better into resource/android/images because if I build for iOS, these images will not be included into the bundle (best practice)

Comment: Look at this it should help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168329/android-screen-sizes-in-pixels-for-ldpi-mdpi-hpdi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168329/android-screen-sizes-in-pixels-for-ldpi-mdpi-hpdi)

Comment: Thanks... I'll take a look. ;)